# A smarter way for evaluating combinations of samples to optimize an overall score

Tags: python, optimization, combinatorics, pandas

I have the following problem (which I simplified for clarity) that I want to find *k* out of *n* samples (here: rows) that yield the maximum `score` (sum of the values in the score column for the *k* rows) where I have to constraints:

1. The sum of the values in the constraint column must be <= threshold
2. There must be a fixed number of samples from each category

Let's say I want to find a combination of 5 rows out of 10 rows that yield the maximum score given that a) the constraint <= 30 and b) 1x category a, 2x category b, 2x category c.

I illustrated the setup in the following figure:

[image]

Now, if I wouldn't have the category constraint, I could just sort the rows by the "score / constraint" ratio (max to min) and start evaluating the combinations from top to bottom, and if I hit the `constraint == threshold` (if there is such a value), I can break the loop early. However, I am wondering if there is another "trick" to find the "optimal" solution without requiring the brute force sampling of all possible combinations.

Putting it into Python code, it would currently look like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_data')

# sort by best score per constraint ratio:
r = df['constraint_column']/df['constraint']
r.sort(ascending=False, inplace=True)
df = df.ix[r.index]

df_a = df[df['category'] == 'a']
df_b = df[df['category'] == 'b'] 
df_c = df[df['category'] == 'c']

best_score = 0.0

for i in product(
            combinations(df_a.index, r=1), 
            combinations(df_b.index, r=2), 
            combinations(df_c.index, r=2)):

    indexes = set(chain.from_iterable(i))
    df_cur = df.ix[indexes]
    if df_cur['constraint_column'].values.sum() > some_threshold:
        continue

    new_score = df_cur['score_column'].values.sum()
    if new_score > best_score:
        best_score = new_score
```

Comment: This is an old question, but if anyone ever comes looking for it they should be aware that this is much more of a math question than a statistics question and would probably benefit from re-asking on math.stackexchange.com